# Oracle ADF: remove blank option in cascading LOVs

Tags: oracle, combobox, oracle-adf, cascadingdropdown, lov

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

I have a problem with cascading LOVs. They finally are working fine, but I have an issue I can't fix, and it's the blank option at first.

I have been trying lot of things:

- setting the *No Selection Item* at first: It does not work. First appears the blank option, then my *'- Select someting-'* item and then the others.
- without setting the *No Selection Item* at first: It does not work. First appears the famous blank option,  then the others.

It does not happen with the main LOV; it happens with the dependent LOV: when value changes in main LOV, the dependent one is always showing the blank option.

Can anyone help me, please? I'm so stuck with this.

Thank you. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that no blank lines returned to your LOV.
You have to uncheck checkbox with **No Selection Item**.
You should make sure, LOV won't get NULL value. If you getting NULLs you might want to fill `unselected` field in jsf component with some text so it will be shown when your LOV got NULLs.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
But, what do you mean with 'no blank lines returned to your LOV'? My query returns fulfilled and actual values, without blanks or null.
Why could I get null values? How can I fix it?

Comment: @yaki_nuka You probably have used that query to define a List Of Values on an atribute in an other view object. If you edit it you will get a popup > UI Hints > The last option is the one Nagh is talking about.

Comment: I still have the same issue. I want to have as a first choice an items that says ALL, so I have to check that box. The issue comes when I check a value from the first LOV and the second and then I press search. After that the second LOV has not only the ALL label bat an empty element...